# restTemplate.getForEntity() get connect timed out

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I use RestTemplate to call a remote api get data and occur an error `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`. But when I use Postman, I get the data (`status=200 time=167ms`)

here is the code:

```
Sting url = "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:8080/api/v1/resources?ak={ak}&ruleno={ruleno}&limit={limit}&offset={offset}&time={time}&ts={ts}&trace_id={trace_id}&sign={sign}";

Map<String, String> urlMap = new HashMap<>();
   urlMap.put("ak", ak);
   urlMap.put("ruleno", ruleNo);
   urlMap.put("limit", limit);
   urlMap.put("offset", offset);
   urlMap.put("time", time);
   urlMap.put("ts", ts);
   urlMap.put("trace_id", traceId);
   urlMap.put("sign", sign);
ResponseEntity<HashMap> result = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, HashMap.class, urlMap);
```

the error is:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_191]

Comment: It is issue related to the network

Answer (score 0):

I have a proxy in browser, so I can use Postman to call the `api`, but when I use java code I have not proxy, so I can't access the `api`.

use this solve the problem:

```
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("my.proxy.com", 9999));
clientHttpRequestFactory.setProxy(proxy);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
```